# How to specify a periodic connection for features of scipy.ndimage.label?

Tags: python, scipy, ndimage

Given an N*N array of 0 and 1, I want to build the list of clusters (a cluster being a set of connected points labeled by 1).

[`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) is very useful because it tells you which points are connected.

But I would like also to have periodic boundary conditions on my array, i.e. points `(0,j)` and `(N,j)` are identified (like a plane that I glue to make a cylinder). So I need to tell scipy.ndimage.label that features are connected through the boundary.

For example, if my original array is:

```
In[187]: a = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]] 

labels = measurements.label(a)
print(labels)
Out [187]: (array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
   [1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]], dtype=int32), 3)
```

and I would like:

```
(array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32), 2)
```

The structure parameter of label allows to specify connection (e.g. features connected even if they touch diagonally), could it be also used for that purpose?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think the structure parameter will help you since it is the local structuring element. What you want is to go over the image boundaries and set labels to be the same according to your boundary conditions.

Comment: By the way, you can improve your question by adding example code to help the community reproduce your problem. In this case an example of a label image (i.e. the output of `scipy.ndimage.label`) and your expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example for imposing a periodic boundary condition on the left and right boundaries. Each label on the right side is identified with the corresponding label on the left side (if it exists).

```
for y in range(label_image.shape[0]):
    if label_image[y, 0] > 0 and label_image[y, -1] > 0:
        label_image[label_image == label_image[y, -1]] = label_image[y, 0]
```

You can do a similar thing for the upper and lower boundaries. You can also come up with any other boundary condition, iterate over the boundary pixels in your `for` loop and check the condition in your `if` statement in a similar manner.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect, thank you ! I did not know you can find where the list elements equals some value this way, that's very nice :D

Comment: That's called 'logical indexing'. It's a super-useful feature of NumPy arrays (inspired by MATLAB) and you should definitely learn to master it!

Comment: If this answers your question you can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark. And if you think this answer is well written you can upvote too :)

Comment: There is a fairly pathological scenario where this methodology fails --- if you have a one-to-one correspondence between periodic regions. That is, if you had two small uniquely labelled "finger lakes" on the left and one big larger lake on the right than spans both, you would label the big right lake with the last visited finger lake label, isolating the first finger lake. Probably a rare occurrence in practice though.

Comment: Note that you could pad the right column of the image with a copy of the left column which would duct all the lakes together.